# Web API Push on iOS/Safari - React App. Really no Service in 2021?

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps, webapi

in a few words: this dilemma is about native push notifications on iOS in a Webapp (React PWA). Is it still completely shut down by Apple? And still not 3rd Party service out there to circumvent this? Unimaginable really, can't tell you how much any hints/suggestions would be valued.

Background info: Truly EVERYTHING was looked into - including services like Pusher Beams, OneSignal etc.

What are your thoughts on the subject and how could this be handled in 2021?

Cheers

Comment: No, Its still not allowed. I don't hope to see in iOS at all.

Answer (score 3):

No, at this time it is not supported, and it doesn't seem to be on the [WebKit Feature Status](https://webkit.org/status/) roadmap.

The best way to support this today would be to feature detect if the Web Push API is available, if it's not, ask the user to sign up for an email notification.

```js
if ('PushManager' in window) {
  // Show UI to request user subscribe to push notifications
} else {
  // Push isn't supported on this browser, show UI to request user
  // subscribe to email notifications.
}
```

Comment: window.PushManager API is not meant only for notifications.
Sometimes, you just want to push some data to your web app.
Apparently, that is not possible even with window.safari.pushNotification API on macOS Safari browser.